# Get value of Observable or value of BehaviourSubject Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have `Observable(variable1)` and `BehaviourSubject(variable2)` and I want to get **values** of both.

```
variable1.value
variable2.value
```

are not working, I get a message 
**Property value doesn't exist on type 'Observable'**.
Could you please tell me how could I get **value**? ('Tiere in Australia')
[image: Here they are]

Comment: Be specific on your question `how to get value from these two` is too board. you want a code snippet or what else

Answer (score 0):

Observable will return all values that it contains when subscribed

```
// creating an Observable
source = Observable.of(1,2,3);

this.source.subscribe(item=>{
  this.values.push(item)
  console.log('observable',this.values)

})
```

BehaviourSubject will return only one value per subscription

```
// creating an BehaviourSubject
subject = new BehaviorSubject(56,121);

this.subject.subscribe(item=>console.log(item))
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/wIpOtueAGfsTYzbCcD5Q?p=preview)**