# Shared service and Observable, BehaviourSubject in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a shared service `SharedService`

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private title = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  currentMessage = this.title.asObservable();
  constructor() { }
  setData(val: string) {
    this.title.next(val);
  }
}
```

I have a component, where I get new data

```
export class Fill implements OnInit {
public title;

  constructor(public shared: SharedService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
this.shared.setData(this.title);
}}
```

And the component Info, where I want read new data 
  export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {

```
  constructor(public shared: SharedService) { 
    this.title = ''; }
  ngOnInit() {

    console.log('i am title from info ')
    this.shared.currentMessage.subscribe(title => this.title = title)
    console.log(this.shared.currentMessage);
    console.log(this.title);
}}
```

In both cases of console.log I get Objects, that contains information, that I need - but I can't retrieve value of it. So, on my console it look like
[image: Message from console]

But if try something like

console.log(this.shared.currentMessage.source.source.value);

it says **Property 'source' is protected and only accessible within class 'Observable' and its subclasses.**

```
this.shared.currentMessage.value
this.title.value
```

doesn't work also...
How could I retrieve data (value) of one or another?

Comment: `ngOnInit` is nested into constructor inside `InfoComponent`.

Comment: Yes. @wostex mentioned it correctly. Keep ngOninit out side of the constructor function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of Observable or value of BehaviourSubject Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766115/get-value-of-observable-or-value-of-behavioursubject-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. **@wostex** mentioned it correctly. Keep `ngOninit` out side of the constructor function and,

```
this.shared.currentMessage.subscribe(title => {

     this.title = title;
     console.log(this.title)
})
```

Comment: And how could I use it later, outside this block? I need to use this data in other function

Comment: For such scenario you can rely on `title` variable defined in the component. You have to use a shared service and define a title variable in service and use it when ever needed.

Comment: In your case service is already there. and `title` is a `behaviourSubject` so whenever you want to fetch data just `subscribe` to `title behaviourSubject`.

Comment: I get the data, right, but a can't get a value from it, that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnInit` has to be Outside the constructor.

And as pointed by @micronkys

As you are subscribing to a observable the value of this.title is not available in the next line as the subscribing is async and so the title dosent get updated . when you log it.

try and use `*ngIf = "title"` in the template like this

```
<div *ngIf = "title">
  {{title}}
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```
this.shared.currentMessage.subscribe((title) => {
                          this.title = title;
                          console.log(this.title)
}
```

Please find a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XqwwUM44NQEpxQVFFxNW?p=preview) for the problem hope you get the answer now

Comment: @AnnaF Also look @ this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) for more on behaviour subject

Comment: @AnnaF updated the answer with a plunker for behaviour subject check that

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I suspect `currentMessage = this.title.asObservable();` is invalid line inside your `SharedService` Injectable.

You could write a method to expose `this.title` expose by `currentMessage` method like below

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  private title = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  //below line was wrong.
  //currentMessage = this.title.asObservable();
  currentMessage(){
     return this.title.asObservable();
  }
  constructor() { }
  setData(val: string) {
    this.title.next(val);
  }
}
//Usage
console.log(this.shared.currentMessage().getValue());
```

---

Yes, you should first take out `ngOnInit` from constructor function. I supposed you want to retrieve initial state of your `BehaviourSubject`, so then you could use [**`.getValue()`**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md#rxbehaviorsubjectprototypegetvalue) function on that Observable without subscribing to stream.

```
console.log(this.shared.currentMessage.getValue());
```

Comment: took outside, getValue doesn't work  Property 'getValue' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'.

Comment: I get an error Property 'getValue' does not exist on type 'Observable<string>'.